How to do contrast-coding with a variable that has 3 levels?
I have recently discovered contrast-coding which compared to dummy-coding just seemed to be a more efficient approach for working with mixed models. Here is the (simplified) logic I followed which will make the question more apparent :

Specifying contrasts...
> contrasts(TASK1_Reaction_Times$TYPE_OF_LEARNING)<-c(-0.5,0.5)
> contrasts(TASK1_Reaction_Times$MOMENT_OF_TEST)<-c(-0.5,0.5)

...centering both variables around 0
> contrasts(TASK1_Reaction_Times$TYPE_OF_LEARNING)
      [,1]
ORTHOGRAPHIC_LEARNING -0.5
PHONOLOGICAL_LEARNING  0.5

> contrasts(TASK1_Reaction_Times$MOMENT_OF_TEST)
          [,1]
IMMEDIATELY -0.5
AFTER_ONE_WEEK 0.5

Building the maximally converging model
> TASK1 <- lmer(RT ~ TYPE_OF_LEARNING * MOMENT_OF_TEST
  + (1 + MOMENT_OF_TEST) + (1 + TYPE_OF_LEARNING), 
   data = TASK1_Reaction_Times)

Checking the summary output
> summary(TASK1)

(...)

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error         df     t value      Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  1000         25         50          40    0.0005 ***
TYPE_OF_LEARNING1             100         25        100          10    0.0005 ***
MOMENT_OF_TEST1              -100         25         50         -10    0.0005 ***
(values are grossly simplified)

It is my understanding that this suggests that the reaction times for participants that had learned the words orthographically are about 100ms faster than participants that had learned the words phonologically;
and that reaction times were on average 100ms slower one week after the initial test.

Here is my question : What do I do if my variable has three levels instead of just two ?
(e.g. three types of learning, three moments of testing)
Is it still possible to use this approach then ? 
How do I contrast-code my variables in such a case (-0.5,0,0.5 ?) ?

Probably easiest to do this via the emmeans package, e.g. see https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=emmeans+contrast+coding

Could you possibly elaborate on that, my proficiency with R and mixed models is rather limited to be honest. A concrete example would allow to better grasp the concept which goes over my head browsing the google follow up links

This question isn't specific to mixed models (it applies to any model with a linear, fixed-effect component, such as lm() or glm()), so I'll illustrate with a built-in data set.
library(emmeans)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
m2 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, contrasts = list(cyl = "contr.sum"))

Default treatment contrasts show the differences between the estimated means for cyl==6 and cyl==8 and the baseline (by default first alphabetical) level, cyl==4
options(show.signif.stars = FALSE)
printCoefmat(coef(summary(m1)), digits = 2)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    26.66       0.97    27.4   <2e-16
cyl6           -6.92       1.56    -4.4    1e-04
cyl8          -11.56       1.30    -8.9    9e-10

Sum-to-zero contrasts show the differences between the first n-1 levels and the (unweighted) overall mean (for two levels this would be equivalent to contrast coding, although maybe (?) with a different scaling)
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    20.50       0.59    34.5   <2e-16
cyl1            6.16       0.82     7.5    3e-08
cyl2           -0.76       0.92    -0.8      0.4

If you want to see the comparisons between every level and the mean, you need something like this (which works regardless of the contrasts used in the original model):
library(emmeans)
contrast(emmeans(m1, ~cyl), "eff")
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 cyl4 effect    6.161 0.817 29   7.544  <.0001
 cyl6 effect   -0.759 0.920 29  -0.825  0.4161
 cyl8 effect   -5.402 0.774 29  -6.976  <.0001

P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests 

Note that the first two contrasts (cyl-4 vs mean, cyl-6 vs mean) are the same as in the previous example.
You can add adjust = "none" if you don't want any multiple-comparisons corrections.
See ?emmeans::eff.emmc for more details.
